# regexp_extract get all matches

Tags: regex, hive, extract

I'm querying a column in `hive`.
This columns contains a `json` payload and is in this format:

```
{"aaa":"xxx", "status":"yes", "bbb":"xyx", "ccc":"yxy", "status":"no", "status":"maybe", "ddd":"zyz"}
```

I'm trying to extract all the status values that appear in different points of the payload.
I'm using the following:

`select regexp_extract (payload,'(?<=status":")(.*?)"') as Status`

This however only returns the first occurrence of status and is missing all the next. How do I get the values after every time Status is repeated?

Thanks

Comment: Try `regexp_extract_all` for a global affect.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it says regexp_extract_all is not a recognised function - maybe Hive doesn't use it :(

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Ideally I can extract all "status" values either as separate cells or a long string that I can then separate! so something like "Yes" "no" "maybe"

Comment: `regexp_extract_all` is available since Spark 3.1 and can be only accessed through a SQL expression string `functions.expr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `REGEXP_REPLACE`, `SPLIT,EXPLODE` and `get_json_object()`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT get_json_object(r, '$.status') AS STATUS
    FROM yourtable t 
     LATERAL VIEW explode(split(regexp_replace(t.payload, ',', '},{'), ',')) t1 AS r
    ) a
WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL;
```

This gives

```
status
yes
no
maybe
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked! My json was badly formatted and initially get_json_object wasn't working but I was able to clean it up and make it work! Thanks again!

Comment: Can we get an answer by using the function `regexp_extract`? As it is done in the question by the way

Answer (score 0):

I guess youre doing this because the json is malformatted containing dulicate keys.

Regular expression using anything-but `[^abc]` notation:

```
/"status":"([^"]*)"/g
```

That will also collect empty string from "status":"", if you want only entries containing a value use:

```
/"status":"([^"]+)"/g
```

Original and best best regex reference is of course `perldoc perlre` :
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this syntax but it returns no value: select regexp_extract (payload,'/"status":"([^"]+)"/g'). it just returns "". Have I included your suggestion in my query wrong? I'm very new to regular expressions and only came up with that logic in my select query thanks to stackoverflow questions so please bear with me if I've done something stupid!!!! I have this json that has different hierarchy of data and the "status" is repeated in different levels of the payload and am trying to "flatten" the data and extracting all status of all levels of the hierarchy.

Comment: Use regexp_extract_all, and remove the slashes and the g flag.

Comment: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:7 Invalid function 'regexp_extract_all' - I'm using Hortonworks and apparently doesn't like the 'regext_extract_all' function :(